# How to get the class attribute of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the value of the class attribute of an element.

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" id="myId" class="myClassName">Click Me</a>
```

`this.id`, `this.href` and `this.text` is working.

My Question is why `this.class` is not working ?

**Note:**

I don't want to use:

`console.log($this.attr('class'));` or `console.log($("a").prop("class"));`

because its very slow.

```
$(function(){
   $("a").on("click",function(){
       console.log(this.id);              // myId
       console.log(this.href);            // http://stackoverflow.com/
       console.log(this.text);            // Click Me
       console.log($("a").prop("class")); // myClassName
   });    
});
```

Comment: Answering the original question: because `class` is a [future reserved word](http://es5.github.io/#x7.6.1) in JS dictionary, one has to always quote it as a property name, writing `this['class']` instead. Therefore non-reserved word - `className` - was used to refer to this attribute instead.

Comment: Using jquery, you can use `attr('class')` method to retrieve the class attribute value ex `console.log($(this).attr('class'))` ... or `hasClass('className')` method to test whether or not your element has a particular class ex `console.log($(this).hasClass('myClassName'))` ... 'this.className' still the fastest way to get the whole value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because it should be `this.className` instead.

**REF:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.className

Answer (score 2):

use `this.className` it is native javascript element property.

```
$(function(){
   $("a").on("click",function(){
       console.log(this.id);              // myId
       console.log(this.href);            // http://stackoverflow.com/
       console.log(this.text);            // Click Me
       console.log(this.className); // myClassName
   });    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `class` attribute maps onto the `className` property (not the non-existent `class` property) in DOM.